# Enviar HTML y pdf a la vez con GmailApp.sendEmail (Google Sripts)

Tags: pdf, script

> ¿como puedo enviar el correo y que coja los dos?

De momento solo consigo que envíe el `pdf` o  el HTML, pero juntos no.
Tengo definido variable pdf(fichero) y otra variable

¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Gracias. JR

```
var blob=copiaArchivo.getBlob()
blob.setName("Informe " + empresa+".PDF")
var pdf=carpeta.createFile(blob)

var htmlfirma= HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('firma')
var htmlmensaje = htmlfirma.evaluate().getContent()
var ophtml = {htmlBody: htmlmensaje}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pude añadir el pdf como un adjunto al email de la siguiente forma:

```
var ophtml = {htmlBody: htmlmensaje,
            attachments:[pdf]}
```